# will my message be added twice to the queue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I've got a function like below:

```
    [FunctionName("OnBlocksQueueTriggered")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("processblocksqueue", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")
        ]string payload,
        [Queue("processschedqueue", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudQueue outputQueue,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
         outputQueue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage("my awesome message"));

    }
```

Since we are specifying an output queue like so in the function signature:

```
        [Queue("processschedqueue", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudQueue outputQueue
```

as well as the line within the function:

```
         outputQueue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage("my awesome message"));
```

**Will the message between added twice?**

Comment: is my answer satisfactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output binding is not working automatically for you. It just wraps the connection for you so that it is more convenient and optimized.

So, no, your message will not be added twice. The way you have implemented it, is the way you should.